# Server send a image as response and rename it before serving - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers, symfony-2.3

I want to serve a image as Response in Symfony 2.3.16

So I'm doing this in my action:

```
$image = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MakoBackendBundle:Image')->find($id); 

if($image !== null) {                                                               
    /** @var $image Image */                                                        
    $info = getimagesize($image->getAbsolutePath());                                
    $content = file_get_contents($image->getAbsolutePath());                        

    return new Response($content, 200, array(                                       
        'Content-Type' => $info['mime'],                                            
        'Content-Length' => strlen($content),                                       
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;'                                      
    ));                                                                             
}                                                                                   

return new Response();
```

My question is how can I serve this image with a different name, like a time based hash or something? I want to serve it with a different name than it is stored on the server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony2 has a helper for this. This is from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files).

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,   // disposition
    'foo.pdf'                                    // filename
);

$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);
```